# select data from database and load into table view in javafx

Tags: javafx

In my application i need to load previously inserted  table view data in javaFX using select statement .i recieved data from database but problem is data does not load into table view.

Comment: How are you loading the data in your application ?

Comment: tableView.setItems(In your database Query list);